# Take float number store into array and load from array?

Tags: mips

```
.data

Arr : .word 40

.text

main:

la $s0,Arr

add $t1,$t1,$zero
add $t2,$t2,$zero

inputloop:
add $t1,$t1,1
beq $t1,5,outputloop


addi $v0,$zero,6
syscall
add $t0,$zero,$v0
mov.s $f1,$f0 

swc1 $f1,0($s0)
add $s0,$s0,4

j inputloop


outputloop:

add $t2,$t2,1
beq $t2,5,exit

lwc1 $f2,0($s0)
add $s0,$s0,4

mov.s $f12,$f2
addi $v0,$zero,2
syscall

j outputloop

exit:

addi $v0,$zero,10
syscall
```

As you can see guys i use two loops,one of these getting float value from user and storing into array, and the second one is just taking from array to just one float number and print it it goes on like that. whats the problem ?

Comment: welcome to SO, could you please elaborate what you want to achieve?

Comment: What value does `$s0` have when you reach `outputloop` the first time? Is that the correct value? (hint: it isn't).